# BERT tokenizer and model without transformers library

Tags: python, pytorch, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to use both `BertTokenizer` and `BertForTokenClassification` offline. The goal of the project is to use these pretrained models and apply them to my own dataset for an NLP task. Due to network and security limitations, I am not able to install the `transformers` library from HuggingFace. I am only able to use PyTorch.

At this point, I have downloaded and saved the following `bert-base-uncased` files from the HuggingFace website to a local directory:

- config.json
- python_model.bin
- vocab.txt

I've used the `transformers` library before, so I'm familiar with initializing the models from local files using something like `BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('/path/to/local')`. However, since I'm not able to install the package and call the model classes, I don't know how to use these downloaded local files in a similar manner. How do I use these local files to use `BertTokenizer` and `BertForTokenClassification`?

I've been instructed to use the following link to implement this: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect? What you need to do is to copy the code from huggingface and of its imports.

Comment: Yeah, my next step was to do exactly that, but I was instructed to use the link below to load the model, and that "the model class is the model itself". The goal is to only use the files. I've asked for some more clarification on how to do this but haven't received much help from those I work with. https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html

Comment: `import torch`
`from transformers import BertForTokenClassification, BertTokenizer`
`t = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')`
`m = BertForTokenClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')`
`torch.save(t, 'theberttokenizer')`
`torch.save(m, 'thebertfortokenclassification')`. This will generate two files which should(!) (I have never tested that) contain everything you need to use it in an pytorch only environment.

Comment: I cannot use the `transformers` library whatsoever, nor can I use it in offline mode. Ultimately my issue is defining the `BertTokenizer()` class without access to the `transformers` library. I only have the three files mentioned in the original post, so I have no idea how to do this or if it's even possible.

Comment: What I meant is that you execute the posted commands on a computer with `transformers` and transfer the generated files to your computer without transformers and see if it works. The other option you have is what I already wrote copy the transformers until you can generate these objects. I think you have a misconception by thinking that these 3 files contain everything and all you need to do is to write 3 lines of python and you are done.

Comment: Ok, thank you for confirming that. I actually was under the impression that I would have to do it in one of the ways you recommended. It seems the person who assigned me this project believes it can be done with these three files only. I will have to ask him again how he expects me to do this without any access to the `transformers` library.